# Bug in Vaadin TestBench GridElement

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-testbench

I want to read the texts of all columns of a table row. My code:

```
        // does not work: t.getFirstVisibleRowIndex()
        List<GridColumnElement> columns = t.getAllColumns();
        for (int col = 0; col < columns.size(); col++) {
            GridColumnElement c = columns.get(col);
            String value = t.getCell(rowNumber, col).getText();
            texts.put(c.getHeaderCell().getText(), value);
            texts.put("#" + (col + 1), value);
        }
```

// vaadin-grid-testbench-6.0.2.jar > GridElement.java

```
    public int getFirstVisibleRowIndex() {
        return ((Long) executeScript(
                "return arguments[0]._firstVisibleIndex+arguments[0]._vidxOffset",
                this)).intValue();
    }
```

The return value of executeScript() is null. This method is not null safe.

Stacktrace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke     "java.lang.Long.intValue()" because the return value of     "com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.testbench.GridElement.executeScript(String, Object[])" is null

at com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.testbench.GridElement.getFirstVisibleRowIndex(GridElement.java:73)

at com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.testbench.GridElement.isRowInView(GridElement.java:176)

at com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.testbench.GridElement.getCell(GridElement.java:116)

at com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.testbench.GridElement.getCell(GridElement.java:101)

Java 17 (Temurin)

**Solution**

If I change 
`String value = t.getCell(rowNumber, col).getText();`
to 
`String value = t.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(c).getText();` it works. Is it a getCell(row, col) bug?

Comment: Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: Vaadin 23.1.2, Vaadin Gradle Plugin 23.0.7, Vaadin-testbench 17.0.2, vaadin-grid-testbench-6.0.2.jar